# Do long sessions of computer use damage the user's skin?

Tags: environmental-health, computers

I believe that regularly spending long periods of time facing computers monitors while using them significantly damages the skin.

The Daily Mail [reported in 2018](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-5377033/How-computer-screens-ruining-skin-stop.html):

> According to [Rebecca Mason, skin expert] the main impact computers can have on our skin is that they give us too much exposure to blue light
>
> [...]
>
> Rebecca explained that overexposure to blue light can affect us in any number of ways, from creating additional cortisol in the body to stopping us from sleeping and even increasing our risk of disease.
>
> The skin expert also said that computer screens will impact your sleep and have a knock-on effect on your skin

[The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/fashion/2017/jun/01/lights-off-is-the-glare-from-your-computer-really-ageing-your-skin) has a report suggesting that blue lights could directly cause hyper-pigmentation or sun damage.

Is it true?

Comment: But the intensity is so low, relative to what you get outside ...

Comment: It won't damage the _skin_, but blue light can interfere with the circadian rhythm and cause insomnia, which has other indirect health effects.